# MySQL - get the rest of string from found one

Tags: mysql, substr

I have an problem, i am using simple query to select from column (VARCHAR), what user searched and appending +1 string to it from database.

For example if i had in `table` following values (`title`):

```
My name is SOMEONE.
Have a great day.
It's possible.
Mouse on the way.
My mouse is on other way.
Is there any mouse?
```

And user wants to retreive the keyword `mouse`.

I wish to output him following from the values above:

```
Mouse on
mouse is
mouse?
```

Also if the user types `Mouse on` it should return
`Mouse on the` **and so on, appending one string from database to found ones (if any).**

I could do it outside of database, but i need after retreiving string DISTINCT values with Limitation.

For now i used `SUBSTRING_INDEX(title , ' ', ".$totalWords.")` 
where $totalWords were the user sent to my programme.

Problem with my query was when you type `other` it will find and return:
`My mouse` but that's not what i want, i want to it output from found string +1 append so it would be `other way`

If i wasn't so clear i will give my best to explain it better.

Thank you.

Comment: I started answering this, but then gave up when I realized how many nasty edge cases there are.  For example, the word `mouse` could be the last word in the sentence, in which case there is no next word, and we would look for punctuation (`.`, `?`, `!`, etc.).  However, if `mouse` occurred in the middle of the string, we'd be looking for a space to mark the end of the next word.

Comment: MySQL has poor regex support, and if I were you, I might handle this in my app layer.

Comment: I will do it through app at the end, if none doesn't know nice and fast feature for doing this in database... Thanks for suggestion! :)

Comment: Certain databases such as Oracle or maybe Postgres could help here, but not MySQL (not without using a UDF or something).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LOCATE(substr,str)` [1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) to locate the position of the first occurence of the user input. afterwards use `SUBSTRING(str FROM pos)` [2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to get a substring starting at the position of the first occurence of the user input and finally use your `SUBSTRING_INDEX(title , ' ', ".$totalWords.")` to get the second word.

PS: Sounds like an autocompletion feature? probably there are better ways to do it than with a relational database

Comment: Yes it's autocomplete feature, and could you suggest the better way to do it? Best regards and thank you for the answer.